# Обновление страницы (AJAX PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Сразу оговорюсь, я дилетант, а не программист, задаю вопрос с целью понимания сути. Есть страница status.php делает запрос на сервер и возвращает ответ в виде:

```
"status_order":"process"
"order_no":""
```

через какое то время ответ меняется(надо обновить стр)

```
"status_order":"done"
"order_no":"xxx"
```

Как сделать так чтобы обновлялся только ответ без полного обновления страницы?

Comment: Вы верите в телепатию? Ну приложите хоть код того, что нужно обновлять на странице

Comment: Да. так и нужно сделать, всё верно.

Answer (score 0):

```
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) {
      console.log('xhr.readyState= ', xhr.readyState);
      return;
    }

    alert(xhr.status != 200 ? xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText: xhr.responseText);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Слишком расплывчатый вопрос. Без конкретики ответить можно только точно так же.
Для начала нужно подготовить PHP скрипт, чтобы он отдавал то что нужно. Пример с текстом.

```
<?php
   $text = 'Изменяющийся текст, нужно выводить его на страницу';
   echo $text;
 ?>
```

Теперь элемент на странице куда это нужно отобразить

```
<div id="text_block" ></div>
```

Теперь JS.
Выбираем его из дом дерева

```
var div = document.getElementById('text_block');
```

Подготавливаем функцию AJAX запроса к этому скрипту. Она принимает элемент в который будет записывать текст.

```
function AJAX(elem){

    // создаем объект запроса
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            data;

    // Заранее подготавливаемся к ответу
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // Когда полностью получим данные
        if( request.readyState === 4 ) {

           // Сюда записываем то что получим от сервера
           data = request.responseText;
           // Записываем полученное значение в переданный елемент
           elem.innerHTML = data;
        }
    };
    // Формируем нужный запрос на нужный адрес, где лежит php скрипт
    request.open('GET','xxxxxx.php');

    // Отправляем
    request.send(); 
}
```

Теперь запускаем нашу функцию с заданным интервалом и передаем в нее блок (переменная div).

```
var timer = setInterval((function(){
   AJAX(div);       
}), 10000);
```

Каждые 10 секунд это значение будет записано в блок заново. Если значение на сервере будет меняться, то будет меняться и на странице без ее перезагрузки.